# Bash if/else statement is not piping output correctly

Tags: bash, shell, if-statement, stdout

I have a script that is querying AWS regions for specified subnet masks. In AWS, the default VPC CIDR block is `172.31.0.0/16`, so I wrote an `if/else` statement to pipe that output to `/dev/null` and then write all other CIDR blocks to a text file. For some reason, the `172.31.0.0/16` block is still being written to the text file.

`Code:`

```
#!/bin/bash

get_cidrs() {
for region in `aws ec2 describe-regions --output text | cut -f3`
do
    echo -e "\nGetting subnets in region:'$region'..."
    describe_cidr=`aws ec2 describe-vpcs --region $region | grep '\Block":' | awk 'NR%2==0' | sed 's/CidrBlock": "//g'`

    echo "$describe_cidr"
    if [[ "$describe_cidr"  == "172.31.0.0/16," ]]; then
        echo "$describe_cidr" > /dev/null 2>&1
    else
        echo "$describe_cidr" >> cidr_blocks.txt
    fi
done
}

get_cidrs
```

`Output:`

```
Getting subnets in region:'eu-central-1'...
                    "172.31.0.0/16",

Getting subnets in region:'us-east-1'...
                    "10.247.92.0/23",
                    "10.247.90.0/23",
```

`Text file:`

```
cat cidr_blocks.txt
"172.31.0.0/16",
"10.247.92.0/23",
"10.247.90.0/23",
```

The goal is to not have any of the `"172.31.0.0/16",` ranges in the text file.

Comment: You are testing for `172.31.0.0/16,` but the actual value coming through is `"172.31.0.0/16",` I'm thinking those double quotes are important, right?

Comment: Might want to use `jq -r` rather than fragile `awk`/`sed`/`grep` constructions.

Comment: @JNevill, yes, I need the output to be wrapped in double quotes.

Comment: `echo "..." > /dev/null` is a no-op; you can replace it with `:`.

Comment: Unless you plan on incorporating `cidr_blocks.txt` back into a larger JSON file (in which case you should change your approach slightly), I don't see why you would need the quotes (or the comma).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, `describe-regions` is capable of outputting the region names you want with no post-processing. (The same may be true of `describe-vpcs`, using an appropriate `--query` option.)

Second, getting the desired CIDR blocks is much simpler if you use a proper tool to parse the JSON output.

```
get_cidrs () {
    aws ec2 describe-regions --query 'Regions[].{Name:RegionName}' --output text |
      while IFS= read -r region; do
        aws ec2 describe-vpcs --region "$region" |
          jq -r '.Vpcs[].CidrBlock | select(. != "172.31.0.0/16")'
      done > cidr_blocks.txt
}
```

Comment: Maybe without the `-r`, since the OP says they want their output to contain literal double quotes. Though I wonder if they can/should be changing their calling code such that the file contains a syntactically valid JSON list, complete with `[` and `]` at the beginning and end.

Comment: Which does? The `describe-regions` (with `--output text` added just now) command is taken directly from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-regions.html#examples. I'm basing the `jq` command on the output shown in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-vpcs.html#examples.

Comment: @chepner, it worked with `--output text`. Thank you!